# Tracking Leaderboard activity lifecyle (Android)

Tags: android, google-play-games, activity-lifecycle, leaderboard, start-activity

I'm trying to make my app as robust and friendly as possible and test it for all possible occurrences.  Now, I am launching a leaderboard in my app like so:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), ID), 1);
```

When the **leaderboard activity** is displayed (over my **main activity**) and the user presses the 'Home' key on their device, and leaves it for a while, one of four things  (I think), can happen:

- 1) Nothing happens and the user is free to return to the app (it will pick up from where is was as it's all still in memory)
- 2) My App's main activity (It only has one activity) is killed by the System along with the Leaderboard activity to free up resources
- 3) My App's main activity is killed by the System to free up resources (but the Leaderboard activity survives)
- 4) The leaderboard activity is killed and the main app survives

Now, when re-launching, I have code in place (using a simple int variable) to track if there was a leaderboard showing at the time the app was paused.

Obviously, this int value can only know the state of the leaderboard at the time the home key was pressed.

When relaunching, how can I know the current state of the leaderboard activity?  How can I know if it's still alive or if the system killed it?  I need to know this so I can handle any scenario. (ie, if its still physically there, then no need to re-launch it).

**Edit**

To summarise, when returning to the app after it previously went into the background, how can I know if the leaderboard activity still exists / is displayed or not?

Comment: A comment would be helpful as to the reason for the close vote. I'm not sure I agree this question it 'too broad', however, I've added an edit which summarises the question in 2 lines :-)

Comment: If you start a leaderboard activity from your main activity and then you close the app, there is no reason for the leaderboard activity to NOT be shown upon relaunch UNLESS it has been destroyed. This is as far as I know. I could be wrong. I suggest you use **startActivityForResult** and see what is happening to the leaderboard activity through the result you obtain from it via **onActivityResult()**

Comment: Thanks @Orgen, I do already use startActivityForResult as the docs say you must use it.  Yeah, in most cases, it will show up again, it's those cases you mention where it's destroyed that I'm concerned with.  If there was a leaderboard showing and the apps is paused and then the system destroys the leaderboard, I want to re-launch the leaderboard on app relaunch, so as to provide a seamless user experience.  However, I can't just re-launch it as it may still be there.  So what I'm after is something like:  If (Leaderboard was there on exit but has been destroyed){show leaderboard}.  Cheers :-)

Comment: Well I can't think of any other way to track the leaderboard intent other than checking any onActivityResult codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out how to do this.  I've tested it and it works perfectly.

I initially declare an Intent as an *instance variable*:

```
private Intent myLeaderboard;
```

Then in my **ShowLeaderboard()** method, I do this:

```
ShowLeaderBoard(){

    //Only create new object if one doesn't currently exist
    if (myLeaderboard==null){    
        myLeaderboard = Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), ID);
    }

    myLeaderboard.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    startActivityForResult(myLeaderboard, 1);

}
```